# how to read multi lines in text file in c#?

Tags: c#, text, readline

i like to read check the text has multi line or single line and then i am going to read that multi lines and convert into single line how can i do this?

Comment: What's a multi-line in this context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really do not need to check as `File.ReadAllLines()` will always return a string array regardless of the number of lines. You can leverage that behavior and simply join the returned array with your separator of choice.

```
string singleLine = string.Join(" ", File.ReadAllLines("filepath"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = String.Empty;
if(textbox.Text.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
{
    //textbox contains a new line, replace new lines with spaces
    text = textbox.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
}
else
{
    //single line - simply assign to variable
    text = textbox.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like that (depends on how you treat "lines"):

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path).Replace("\n\r", "");
```

Comment: The correct CRLF would be `"\r\n"`. But much better would be `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 0):

This will read all the lines from a text file and join them into one string with ; as a separator:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("myfile.txt");
string myLine = String.Join(";", lines);
```