# How to read an entire file to a string using C#?

Tags: c#, string, file-io, .net-3.5

What is the quickest way to read a text file into a string variable?

I understand it can be done in several ways, such as read individual bytes and then convert those to string. I was looking for a method with minimal coding.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855335/how-to-read-multi-lines-in-text-file-in-c

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-Read-a-Text-File-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 488, accepted):

How about [`File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext):

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\test.txt");
```

Comment: Not the best function to use, though. As [Devendra D. Chavan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/529196/devendra-d-chavan) points out in his answer, `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` is more efficient.

Comment: @OwenBlacker It depends on whether "quickest" means "least time to execute" or "least time to understand."

Comment: File.ReadAllText is definitively the easiest one to use, but as "Devendra D. Chavan" points out, it is not the fastest. So if you are reading small files, then it would be a better choice to use File.ReadAllText.it really depends on how big the textfiles are that you are reading.

Comment: To **read from the server** check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6582979/2218697), hope helps someone.

Comment: When developing and you need to load some data, this is good enough. It's easy to use for something temporary that will be removed eventually.

Comment: @OwenBlacker -- are you sure?  The benchmark shows that `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` is more efficient than `ReadAllLines`.  Which is to be expected, as the latter also splits the text into lines.  But we are talking about a different method, `ReadAllText`.  Indeed the answer you mention shows that `ReadAllText` just calls `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` internally.

Answer (score 189):

A benchmark comparison of `File.ReadAllLines` vs `StreamReader ReadLine` from [C# file handling](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-handling)

[image: File Read Comparison]

> Results. StreamReader is much faster for large files with 10,000+
>   lines, but the difference for smaller files is negligible. As always,
>   plan for varying sizes of files, and use File.ReadAllLines only when
>   performance isn't critical.

### StreamReader approach

As the `File.ReadAllText` approach has been suggested by others, you can also try the *quicker* (I have not tested quantitatively the performance impact, but it appears to be faster than `File.ReadAllText` (see **comparison** below)). The [difference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163670.aspx#S5)  in performance will be visible only in case of larger files though.

```
string readContents;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8))
{
     readContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

### Comparison of File.Readxxx() vs StreamReader.Readxxx()

Viewing the indicative code through [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) I have found the following about `File.ReadAllLines`, `File.ReadAllText`.

- **`File.ReadAllText`**  - Uses `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` internally
- **`File.ReadAllLines`**  - Also uses `StreamReader.ReadLine` internally with the additionally overhead of creating the `List<string>` to return as the read lines and looping till the end of file.

So both the methods are an *additional layer of convenience* built on top of `StreamReader`. This is evident by the indicative body of the method.

**`File.ReadAllText()`** implementation as decompiled by ILSpy

```
public static string ReadAllText(string path)
{
    if (path == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    }
    if (path.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyPath"));
    }
    return File.InternalReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8);
}   

private static string InternalReadAllText(string path, Encoding encoding)
{
    string result;
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path, encoding))
    {
        result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you compare against `File.ReadAllText`, too ??

Comment: ILSpy suggests that `File.ReadAllText()` is simply a wrapper over `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`. I am guessing that the additional layer should perform slightly slower than `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`.

Comment: Great answer.  Perhaps a little bit much explanation for those just looking for the fix, but it deserves at least as many votes as the chosen answer.

Comment: @Devendra D. Chavan: Offtopic, but where can I find reference or documentation for ILSpy?

Comment: You can also find the code here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,c193e57831aa94a9. What I don't get, is why there is this significant difference in speed if `ReadAllText` is just a wrapper for `streamReader.ReadToEnd();`?

Answer (score 16):

```
string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)
```

Here's the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

For the noobs out there who find this stuff fun and interesting, the fastest way to read an entire file into a string in most cases ([according to these benchmarks](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-read-text-files)) is by the following:

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
{
        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
//you then have to process the string
```

However, the absolute fastest to read a text file overall appears to be the following:

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
{
        string s = String.Empty;
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
               //do what you have to here
        }
}
```

[Put up against several other techniques](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-read-text-files), it won out most of the time, including against the BufferedReader.

Comment: Comment is late I know, but a little confused on your benchmarks here and on the linked page.  It appears to be testing read speeds only and not loading into an entire string.  The second code snippet is reading a line at a time and not doing any appending so the "do what you have to here" would need to have a string builder or string to hold the data.  At which point the memory used to add more data would change the test results.  So s will usually be the same size assuming a fixed width file so the memory will be set for the size of a line and data won't need to be copied to new memory.

Comment: I downvoted this comparison because they're looking at two different things. The first one gets the whole file into a string. The second one reads line-by-line, never having the whole file in a single string -- and not matching the "how to read an entire file to a string" question.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the [File.ReadAllText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) method

Some important remarks:

> This method opens a file, reads each line of the file, and then adds
>   each line as an element of a string. It then closes the file. A line
>   is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return
>   ('\r'), a line feed ('\n'), or a carriage return immediately followed
>   by a line feed. The resulting string does not contain the terminating
>   carriage return and/or line feed.
>
> This method attempts to automatically detect the encoding of a file
>   based on the presence of byte order marks. Encoding formats UTF-8 and
>   UTF-32 (both big-endian and little-endian) can be detected.
>
> Use the ReadAllText(String, Encoding) method overload when reading
>   files that might contain imported text, because unrecognized
>   characters may not be read correctly.
>
> The file handle is guaranteed to be closed by this method, even if
>   exceptions are raised

Answer (score 6):

`string text = File.ReadAllText("Path");` you have all text in one string variable. If you need each line individually you can use this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Path");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
   new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want to pick file from Bin folder of the application then you can try following and don't forget to do exception handling.

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"FilesFolder\Sample.txt"));
```

Answer (score 4):

@Cris sorry .This is quote `MSDN Microsoft`

Methodology

In this experiment, two classes will be compared. The `StreamReader` and the `FileStream` class will be directed to read two files of 10K and 200K in their entirety from the application directory.

```
StreamReader (VB.NET)

sr = New StreamReader(strFileName)
Do
  line = sr.ReadLine()
Loop Until line Is Nothing
sr.Close()

FileStream (VB.NET)

Dim fs As FileStream
Dim temp As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding(True)
Dim b(1024) As Byte
fs = File.OpenRead(strFileName)
Do While fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0
    temp.GetString(b, 0, b.Length)
Loop
fs.Close()
```

Result

[image]

`FileStream` is obviously faster in this test. It takes an additional 50% more time for `StreamReader` to read the small file. For the large file, it took an additional 27% of the time.

`StreamReader` is specifically looking for line breaks while `FileStream` does not. This will account for some of the extra time.

Recommendations

Depending on what the application needs to do with a section of data, there may be additional parsing that will require additional processing time. Consider a scenario where a file has columns of data and the rows are `CR/LF` delimited. The `StreamReader` would work down the line of text looking for the `CR/LF`, and then the application would do additional parsing looking for a specific location of data. (Did you think String. SubString comes without a price?)

On the other hand, the `FileStream` reads the data in chunks and a proactive developer could write a little more logic to use the stream to his benefit. If the needed data is in specific positions in the file, this is certainly the way to go as it keeps the memory usage down.

`FileStream` is the better mechanism for speed but will take more logic.

Comment: But what about `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` ?

Answer (score 3):

well the quickest way meaning with the least possible C# code is probably this one:

```
string readText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use :

```
 public static void ReadFileToEnd()
{
    try
    {
    //provide to reader your complete text file
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( @"C:\file.txt" );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
public static string ReadFileAndFetchStringInSingleLine(string file)
    {
        StringBuilder sb;
        try
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
                    {
                        string str;
                        while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            sb.Append(str);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can read a text from a text file in to string as follows also

```
string str = "";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\Sample.txt");
while(sr.Peek() != -1)
{
  str = str + sr.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a comparison between a ReadAllText and StreamBuffer for a 2Mb csv and it seemed that the difference was quite small but ReadAllText seemed to take the upper hand from the times taken to complete functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using the **File.ReadLines(path)** compare to StreamReader or any other File reading methods. Please find below the detailed performance benchmark for both small-size file and large-size file.
I hope this would help.

**File operations read result:**

**For small file (just 8 lines)**

[image]

**For larger file (128465 lines)**

[image]

**Readlines Example:**

```
public void ReadFileUsingReadLines()
{
    var contents = File.ReadLines(path);
}
```

Note : Benchmark is done in **.NET 6**.

Answer (score -1):

This comment is for those who are trying to read the complete text file in winform using c++ with the help of C# ReadAllText function

```cpp
using namespace System::IO;

String filename = gcnew String(charfilename);
if(System::IO::File::Exists(filename))
{
     String ^ data = gcnew String(System::IO::File::RealAllText(filename)->Replace("\0", Environment::Newline));
     textBox1->Text = data;
}
```