# How do you get the markup of a webpage in asp.net similar to php's get_file_contents

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to do something similar to the PHP command get_file_contents to get the market up a webpage, but it has to be in ASP.net.  I wasnt sure if i could just open the webpage via file, and then just read the stream into another file.

One thought iw as thinking was: [How to read an entire file to a string using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387085/how-to-read-an-entire-file-to-a-string-using-c-sharp) but i wasnt sure if that was the route i would be needing to go or if someone else knew something that would do what i wanted.

Looking for the answer to the following pseudocode:

```
$test = "www.google.com";
$string = get_file_contents($test);
$filePointer = fopen("sample.txt", "w+");
$filePointer.write($string);
fclose($filePointer);
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes WITHOUT giving an explaination.  That's real classy of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string html;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    html = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
}
Console.WriteLine(html);
```

Comment: what is reader in reference to?  It seems in what he is writing vs his code sample is that between the stream and request, there is some sort of StreadReader reader ... but i am unsure as to how to link Stream with StreamReader.

Comment: both examples you had given work under 1 circumstance.  They have to be non-secure pages.  YOu get an authorization error for secure pages because cookies and such are not set.

Comment: @Fallenreaper I am not sure if you are referencing SSL or authentication. The former works fine with the code above. If you are talking about authentication, that was not mentioned in your question, and would require more specifics, as there are many ways of locking down web pages.

Comment: I currently have a new question up, but i am going to reformulate it in a way which is easily understandable.  The issue that i am working around is Authentication

Answer (score -1):

figured this might be what i was looking at:  http://www.devprise.com/2006/07/14/c-method-to-mimic-php-file_get_contents/  Not sure though.