# Getting an error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. from WebClient class

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, xpath

```
item = 535;
String URI = "http://localhost:3033/WebFormDesigner.aspx?fm_id=" + item.ToString();
//String URI = "http://www.google.com";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
Stream s = wc.OpenRead(URI);
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(s);
```

It doesnt work with:

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(URI);
```

in the above method, using the google URI works, but it doesnt seem to like the URI for localhost at all.  I confirmed that the URI works when put into the browser.  Not quite sure whats going on with it.

The error occurs on the Stream declaration.

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

This is an extension of my other post: [How do you get the markup of a webpage in asp.net similar to php's get_file_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033331/how-do-you-get-the-markup-of-a-webpage-in-asp-net-similar-to-phps-get-file-cont)

**Edit: The issue being looked at here, is that there arent permissions to see the page.  The page being visited is a secure page.  What I am trying to do is to give my Request the permissions because the pages are within the same project, but using a WebRequest which assumes it is an outside source.**

I was trying to accomplish with a couple different attempted.  Both involved the cookies.

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(URI);
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        HttpCookieCollection cookieJar = Request.Cookies;
        //foreach (string cookieString in Request.Cookies)
        for(int i = 0; i < cookieJar.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Web.HttpCookie cookie = cookieJar.Get(i);
            Cookie oC = new Cookie();
            oC.Domain = Request.Url.Host;
            oC.Expires = cookie.Expires;
            oC.Name = cookie.Name;
            oC.Path = cookie.Path;
            oC.Secure = cookie.Secure;
            oC.Value = cookie.Value;
            request.CookieContainer.Add(oC);
        }
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
```

This does some pretty simple stuff, but i guess i am still doing it wrong.  I get the cookies for my current page, and pass them into the cookiecollection for the target page.  After that, i submit the request for a response.  It gives the error above as well.

Comment: do you have authentication turned on for that web site?

Comment: It is a secure page, but i didnt know if that would do a whole lot of meaning.  I thought it would be opened the same way.  Im just trying to get the markup of the page, and then parse through it with XPath

Comment: since its a secured page, theres likely a redirect happening. you will have to authenticate to get that page.

Comment: How would i go about authenticating in such a way to accomplish my goal?  I was thinking that maybe in the process of setting up the backend, there might be some session variables being set and adjusted which do all this stuff.  Is it accomplishible to verify with these methods?