# Read utf8 file to QString in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

How can I read an entire UTF-8 encoded file to a QString in Qt, and is there a one-liner similar to [C#'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7387108/492336) `string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\test.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

The shortest I got to was this:

```
QFile f("foo.txt");
f.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString s = QString::fromUtf8(f.readAll());
```

I was hoping to use something like `QString::fromUtf8(QFile("foo.txt").readAll())` which is a one-liner albeit clunky, but the constructor doesn't open the file, so you need to declare a variable and the shortest is 3 lines.