# I need to use text from textfile in my application, and I cant ge it working

Tags: c#

I'm building application and I ran into a little problem. My application should show our workers, when they arrive to work and and where they headed.
I have a datetime picker there and a every new day, when I fill out the application, it should create a new writeline, like this:

5th August Prague

6th August Pilsen
etc...

I have only what I'm showing you and it creates a new textfile every time i try it. Please help.

This is all i have

```
        StreamWriter dc = new 
        StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\dejv2\Desktop\Program Test\Docházka\David 
        Cáder"+ "Docházka David Cáder.txt");          
        if (textBox1.Text == "David Cáder")
        {
            dc.WriteLine(dateTimePicker1.Text + " - David Cáder - " + 
        textBox56.Text);

        }
```

Comment: It looks like missing some code!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read an entire file to a string using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387085/how-to-read-an-entire-file-to-a-string-using-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\dejv2\Desktop\Program Test\Docházka\David 
Cáder"+ "Docházka David Cáder.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter dc = new StreamWriter(fs);
        if (textBox1.Text == "David Cáder")
{
    dc.WriteLine(dateTimePicker1.Text + " - David Cáder - " + 
textBox56.Text);

    }
        dc.Close();
        fs.Close();
```

Other solution using FileStream hopefully this will work as well

Answer (score 0):

The `StreamWriter` constructor you are using **always** creates a new file. You can try using the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Text_Encoding_) that allows you to append to an existing file.

Comment: @DavidCáder there are examples in the documentation page that I provided the link to. Here is one example copied from that Web page: `StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, true, Encoding.UTF8, 512)`

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\dejv2\Desktop\Program Test\Docházka\David 
Cáder"+ "Docházka David Cáder.txt");
string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close()
StreamWriter dc = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\dejv2\Desktop\Program Test\Docházka\David 
Cáder"+ "Docházka David Cáder.txt");
dc.WriteLine(str);
if (textBox1.Text == "David Cáder")
{
    dc.WriteLine(dateTimePicker1.Text + " - David Cáder - " + 
textBox56.Text);

    }
```

I have edit the code now hopefully it will work

Comment: It tells me, that the StreamReader can't get to the file, because it's used by another process.

Comment: read data from file using StreamReader and close it then Write data back to it

Comment: Hello, sorry to bother. It was working for a while, but now itš giving me error: UnauthorizedAccesException, can you help me with that?

Comment: @DavidCáder it looks like file is open it text editor so please close it before running program BTY I am adding another solution this will work as well as you expections

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way :

```
    var content = new List<string>();
    if (textBox1.Text == "David Cáder")
    {
        content.Add(dateTimePicker1.Text + " - David Cáder - " + textBox56.Text)
    }

    File.AppendAllLines((@"C:\Users\dejv2\Desktop\Program Test\Docházka\DavidCáder" + "Docházka David Cáder.txt", content);
```

if you want to use StreamReader & StreamWriter be sure to close the file :

```
    string content = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\dejv2\Desktop\Program Test\Docházka\DavidCáder" + "Docházka David Cáder.txt"))
    {
        content = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    using (StreamWriter dc = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\dejv2\Desktop\Program Test\Docházka\DavidCáder" + "Docházka David Cáder.txt"))
    {
        dc.WriteLine(content);

        if (textBox1.Text == "David Cáder")
        {
            dc.WriteLine(dateTimePicker1.Text + " - David Cáder - " + textBox56.Text);
        }
    }
```