# C# How do I convert file itself into base64

Tags: c#

How do I get the data of the file instead of the path?
I used `Directory.GetFile()` and it returns the path of the file.
Now what I want is to convert the file(not the path) into base64. I know how to convert it to base64 but what I want to know is how do I get the data of the file.

Any idea? Sorry I'm new to c#

I dont know if  `data` is the right terminology here :)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387085/how-to-read-an-entire-file-to-a-string-using-c) might be worth looking at.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting file into Base64String and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919387/converting-file-into-base64string-and-back-again)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a built-in Convert-funtion:

```
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("path");
String base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: Is this applicable to images tho?